# can not upgrade compiled sdk version to 27

Tags: android

I use android studio 2.3.3 with compiled sdk version 26.I 've added https://maven.google.com to repositories in all projects block as it said, but still unable to change and sync support libraries.It comes with the "failed to resolve " message
I do appreciate any help.

This is build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.xxx.yyyy"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
 }

 allprojects {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven{ url "https://maven.google.com" }
    maven{ url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZCiM27ZPJBNBNv4WhHLDAaiU27xXLdkAyby

Comment: show your `build.gradle` file ?

Answer (score 0):

> can not upgrade compiled sdk version to 27

You should set

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

Then modify ***PROJECT LEVEL*** `build.gradle`  section

1. Upgrade **`tools.build:gradle`**
2. Add **`google()`**

**DEMO**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
        maven {

        }
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 27.0.3
Install Build Tools 27.0.3 and sync project

Comment: @RaminShirzad Click on ERROR and sync project

Comment: @RaminShirzad  use `appcompat-v7:27.1.0'` instead of `26.1.0`

Comment: still the same.

Comment: @RaminShirzad what error showing?? Clean-rebuild-run

Comment: failed to find build tools revision 27.0.3

Comment: I did and it worked.I have updated both android studio to 3.1.3 and gradle to 4.4 . Now it has problem with classpath in the project build.gradle dependency.I let upgrading to continue and see what happens.thank you

Answer (score 0):

App build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.1.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.xxx.yyyy"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
 }

 allprojects {
 repositories {

 maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
            name 'Google'
        }

 maven{ url "https://jitpack.io" }

        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

      }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also, add this :

`compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0`

and delete this:

`compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0`

Comment: Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 27.0.3
       <a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 27.0.3 and sync project</a>

Comment: I've updated my code.Try this, and let me know the result.

Comment: I did and it worked.I have updated both android studio to 3.1.3 and gradle to 4.4 . Now it has problem with classpath in the project build.gradle dependency.I let upgrading to continue and see what happens.thank you

Comment: Send me a screenshot so that I can help you about it.

Comment: @RaminShirzad can you please update your code with the changes or simply post new code in your question. Because it is not clear what is happening in your code, just with the screenshots you provided.